# Bootstrap toggle menu on one page site does not uncollapse when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and it is a one page site. And when I need to use the toggle for mobile devices. The collapse works, but I need to uncollapse when I click on one of the menu liks.

Just need that to deliver the project.

Any thoughts?

http://www.neevasoft.com/docasnovo

html

```
<header id="header" class="navbar-fixed-top main-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <!-- Logo start -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>   

                </div><!--/ Logo end -->

                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse clearfix" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">A Empresa</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#historia">História</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Participações</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Renovada</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="acervo.html" onClick="window.location='acervo.html'">Acervo</a></li>
                        <!--li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li-->

                    </ul>

                </nav><!--/ Navigation end -->

            </div><!--/ Col end -->
        </div><!--/ Row end -->
    </div><!--/ Container end -->
</header><!--/ Header end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add to each li the following attributes:

```
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
</li>
....
....
```

no need for JavaScript code here. because bootstrap will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.collapse('hide')` from `collapse.js`. [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("li a.page-scroll").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: `.closest('nav')` might find other things, use `.closest('.navbar-collapse.in')`

Comment: @tricks-for-the-web True that, edited. This was just a quick fiddle anyways, haven't even tested it.